# Meteor sort/limit publication doesn't work as expected - X documents are overflowing the set

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

The following was observed on Meteor **0.8.0.1**.

I'm using a Meteor publication to watch the most recent X log entries recorded in a collection:

```js
Meteor.publish "tsGroupLogs", (groupId, limit) ->
  return null unless isAdmin(@userId)

  return Logs.find({_groupId: groupId}, {
      sort: {_timestamp: -1},
      limit: limit
    })
```

Generating events into this log causes strange behavior:

- First, the subscription doesn't see the events (even though they have
  the most recent timestamp).
- Second, a forced reload of the subscription results in the following
  errors in the server console:

  ```js
  I20140430-21:07:45.118(-4)? Error in oplog callback Error: After adding to published, 2 documents are overflowing the set
  I20140430-21:07:45.119(-4)?     at _.extend._addPublished (packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_observe_driver.js:176)
  I20140430-21:07:45.119(-4)?     at _.extend._addMatching (packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_observe_driver.js:313)
  I20140430-21:07:45.119(-4)?     at _.extend._handleOplogEntrySteadyOrFetching (packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_observe_driver.js:509)
  I20140430-21:07:45.119(-4)?     at packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_observe_driver.js:118
  I20140430-21:07:45.119(-4)?     at packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_observe_driver.js:16
  I20140430-21:07:45.119(-4)?     at Object.Meteor._noYieldsAllowed (packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:15)
  I20140430-21:07:45.119(-4)?     at packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_observe_driver.js:106
  I20140430-21:07:45.119(-4)?     at packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_tailing.js:79
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:89)
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:102
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at packages/livedata/crossbar.js:68
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113)
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at _.extend.fire (packages/livedata/crossbar.js:66)
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_tailing.js:207
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at loop (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:924)
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:37)
  I20140430-21:07:45.120(-4)?     at packages/meteor/timers.js:6
  I20140430-21:07:45.121(-4)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:89)
  ```

This looks like something to do with how the [oplog observe driver](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver) handles queries with `sort` and `limit` parameters, but I don't see anything specifically I'm doing wrong.

This is the relevant line of code: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo-livedata/oplog_observe_driver.js#L183

Any ideas about what is causing this error?

Comment: The error message you are seeing is an assertion. The idea of it is: if something was added into the result set, and the result set was full before (all `limit` places were taken) then only 1 doc would overflow outside of it. For some reason you are seeing 2 docs overflowing which is not right and the assertion catches it.

Comment: I don't think the information you have given is sufficient to dig it. If you think it is a bug in the implementation of observe driver, please open a GH ticket with a repro. Thank you Andrew.

Comment: @imslavko It's very hard to debug, because now in 0.8.1 the subscription doesn't send any data at all (nothing changed other than a `meteor update`). So I'm not sure whether to try and go after the bug in 0.8.1 or go back to 0.8.0 and try and figure out what is going on here. Do you have any information about the changes that would have led to this and which you'd rather me try and dig into?

Comment: @imslavko I'm also seeing things like `6 documents are overflowing the set`, etc, after I generate 6 log events and force a refresh. So something was going seriously nuts here.

Comment: I don't understand what is assumed by "Force a refresh". In diff 0.8.0..0.8.1 glasser fixed some phase transitions but I don't see how they could change the behavior you are seeing directly. It might be a worse issue than "overflowing docs". I feel like it is some sort of race.

Comment: Probably a bug repro for 0.8.1 is more valuable

Comment: Do you seen any corresponding errors in MongoD logs? Can you attach that as well?

Comment: @imslavko 0.8.0 had the issue I described above where inserting into the collection caused nothing to happen at all on the client. Upon manually refreshing the client page, the items appeared and the overflowing message shows up. In 0.8.1 nothing is getting sent over to the client. I feel like the errors might be caused by the same underlying issue, but the way it's handled has changed from 0.8.0..0.8.1.

Comment: @AndrewMao I have the same intuition. But you know, the best clue you can give us is a repro.

Comment: @imslavko These were two separate issues. A difference in how publication arguments were handled resulted in no data being sent in 0.8.1. Once I fixed that, there were no `overflowing the set` errors anymore on 0.8.1 - I think whatever bug was causing this has been fixed.